# ¿Es posible conseguir que una aplicación se ejecute como "Aplicación protegida" por defecto?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

necesito utilizar las notificaciones push en mi aplicación creada con meteor y cordova.

Estoy utilizando el plgin raix:push para enviar las notificaciones, y todo funciona correctamente cuando la app se esta ejecutando en el background, pero no cuando está totalmente cerrada.

Trasteando en los ajustes del móvil he descubierto que si activo mi aplicación como aplicación protegida todo funciona correctamente incluso con la aplicación cerrada.

¿Existe alguna manera de que esta opción se active por defecto cuando se instale?

Quizá alguna opción en el archivo mobile config o algo así pueda ayudar, pero no se como hacerlo

Gracias Anticipadas.

Comment: "aplicación protegida", no te refieres a aplicación del sistema?

Comment: No, "Aplicaciones protegidas" es una opción que aparece en los ajustes de sistema en android. No se si otros dispositivos distintos al mío lo traducirán de otra forma. En esa opción aparecen todas las aplicaciones que siguen ejecutándose incluso cerradas (whatsapp y aplicaciones del sistema).